# collada-dom2.4-sp-dev causes dist-upgrade to fail on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We need to do a dist-upgrade this morning and ran into a problem with the machines that have ros installed on them.  I had to comment out the ros apt file and remove several ros packages to get ubuntu updates to install.  After that I went back and tried to reinstall `ros-indigo-desktop-full`. The new `collada-dom2.4-sp-dev` gives the following error:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  collada-dom-dev collada-dom2.4-sp-dev ros-indigo-collada-parser
  ros-indigo-collada-urdf ros-indigo-desktop ros-indigo-desktop-full
  ros-indigo-robot ros-indigo-robot-model ros-indigo-simulators


Unpacking collada-dom2.4-sp-dev (2.4.4.1-ubuntu1~trusty1) ...  dpkg:
error processing archive
/var/cache/apt/archives/collada-dom2.4-sp-dev_2.4.4.1-ubuntu1~trusty1_amd64.deb
(--unpack): trying to overwrite
'/usr/lib/cmake/collada_dom-2.4/collada_dom-config.cmake', which is also
in package collada-dom2.4-dp-dev 2.4.4.0-ubuntu1~trusty1 dpkg-deb:
error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222892/collada-dom2.4-sp-dev-causes-dist-upgrade-to-fail-on-ubuntu-14.04/) by [pknettle](https://answers.ros.org/users/25389/pknettle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-12-21

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-21**:
Are you using the `shadow-fixed` repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problems of this kind are common with the ROS repository. It is so easy to specify a conflict in the .deb config file!
Try:

```
 sudo dpkg --purge --force-all collada-dom2.4-dp-dev
```

and than you can

```
 sudo apt-get install -f
```

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2015-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-21**:
It's also easy to declare this in your `package.xml` using the [conflict](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html#conflict-multiple) and [replace](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html#replace-multiple) tags. I'd report this to the package maintainer, as it's clearly unintended.

**Comment by [pknettle](https://answers.ros.org/users/25389/pknettle/) on 2015-12-21**:
I tried that right after I posted the question and it worked.  Thanks for the reply.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-21**:
I added a comment to [robot_model/issues/118](https://github.com/ros/robot_model/issues/118).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-22**:
And tracked at [collada-dom/issues/20](https://github.com/rdiankov/collada-dom/issues/20). Should already be fixed in-source, not sure when new pkgs will be imported.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2015-12-23**:
The changes are still not in the repository. But thank you very much for reporting, gvdhoorn.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-23**:
Syncing will take a while. I wouldn't have expected them to be available already.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been solved as of 31, Dec, 2015, with 2.4.4.4 of collada-dom-dev. Sorry for trouble.

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2015-12-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2015-12-30**:
also see http://lists.ros.org/lurker/thread/20151225.002725.4ef881c4.en.html